# Clean array destructuring of global regex matches in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, destructuring

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, but is there a clean method of looping over the matches of a global regex and destructuring each match in one line?  The cleanest approach I can think of is:

```js
let regex = /(a)(b)?(c*)/g,
  str = 'cabcccaccaaabbacb',
  match, a, otherCaptures;

while (([match, a, ...otherCaptures] = regex.exec(str) || []).length) {
  // do stuff
  console.log(match, a, otherCaptures);
}
```

If you don't include the `|| []`, it tries to destructure `null` which throws an error.  The empty array is truthy, so the best method I can think of is to check its length.  Since you can't wrap a `let` statement in parentheses and then call a member of it, the variable declaration needs to happen outside the scope of the `while` which is undesirable.

Ideally there'd be a clever way to avoid the `|| []`, but I haven't thought of one, short of adding a `matches()` member to `RegExp.prototype` (which might just be the ideal solution anyway).

Comment: why not destructure inside the body of the loop? `while (m = regex.exec(str)) { const [match, a, ...otherCaptures] = m; ... }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I did not know about codereview... thanks!

Comment: @darrenSweeney I disagree, not sure if it better fits on CodeReview.

Comment: @ibrahim / hamms "great minds think alike" or "drei Dumme ein Gedanke" ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms `The cleanest approach I can think of is:` is what prompted me, it's basically saying `is there a better approach, or, can you review this` - fine line though, interpretation is hugely open to misinterpretation

Comment: @darren afaik code review does not really fit for oneliners ... but I'm not that active over there ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just destructure one line later:

```
 let part; 
 while(part = regex.exec(str)) {
   const [match, a, ...otherCaptures] = part;
   //...
 }
```

With a for loop the `part` can also be local scoped:

```
 for(let part; part = regex.exec(str); ) {
   const [match, a, ...otherCaptures] = part;
   //...
 }
```

Comment: This seems to be the consensus.  I'll mark it as the answer when it lets me in 6 minutes.  Still, I am curious if there's a way to do it within the while statement, or within a for loop.

Comment: @dfoverdx There is a way to do it inside `while` statement, you already used it.

Comment: You've got a typo in the for loop.  Missing a period after `regex`.